# Discord.js | How do I make a code that sends the users info when they join?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a code that sends the users avatar, username, ID, account create date, joined server date and status automatically when they join

it looks something like this

```
module.exports = (Discord, client, message) => {

    const ChannelID = ('731452498761613366');


    const userEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`Here is what I found about the kid`)
    .setThumbnail(displayAvatarURL())
    .addField('Username and tag:', )
    .addField('User ID:', )
    .addField('Account created:', )
    .addField('Joined the server at:', )
    .addField('User status:', )
    .setColor('5E61AB')



    guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get(ChannelID).send(userEmbed).catch(err =>  console.log(err));

}
```

Idk what to put at after the `:` but I know the `.tag`, `.id`, `.createdAt` `.joinedAt` and `.presence.status`. I don't know what to put before the `.`. I also don't use `client.on` because I have a specific folder called events. Sorry if my question is hard to understand or I'm asking a bad question or anything. Does anybody know how I can make this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [`guildMemberAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd) event for this. It's pretty simple:

#### First:

create a new file *( or add it to the file all your events are defined )* named `guildmMemberAdd.js`

#### After that

you can define the `event` like this:

##### *Code, if you're using a `command handler`:*

```js
// The order of the parameters may differ
module.exports = (Discord, member) => {
  // your code here
}
```

##### *Code, if you're defining all events in your `main file`:*

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
  // your code here
});
```

---

Now that you covered that, you can create your `embed` *(this will work for both options that I showed above)*:

```js
const newMemberEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`Here is what I found about the kid`)
    .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL())
    .addField(`Username and tag: ${member.displayName} | ${member.user.tag}`, )
    .addField(`User ID: ${member.id}`, )
    .addField(`Account created: ${member.user.createdAt}`, )
    .addField(`Joined the server at: ${member.joinedAt}`, )
    .addField(`User status: ${member.presence.status}`, )
    .setColor('5E61AB')
```

If you're done with that, you're ready to `send` the `embed`:

```js
const ChannelID = ('731452498761613366');

member.guild.channels.cache.get(ChannelID).send(newMemberEmbed).catch(err =>  console.log(err));
```

Hope this works :)

---

#### References:

- [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember)
- [`Embeds` guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-embed-constructor)

Comment: It says that `displayavatarURL is not defined`, what do I do?

Comment: I forgot `member.user.[...]`. I updated it in my answer

Comment: now I get `Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined`, how do I declare it?

Comment: Log `member` and see what it is. Your error means that `member.guild` doesn't exist, so it's probable `member` isn't what you think

Comment: @Lioness100 I logged member and it sent a bunch of lines that I cannot comprehend. I tried looking at it and the only thing I found relevant was `guildMemberAdd: [Function: bound ],` and at the bottom, it still says `Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined`

Comment: Are you using an event handler?

Comment: @Lioness100 Yes, I am. I made 2 separate events which are client and guild. I put this in the guild event.

Comment: Please show some of your code so I can understand better

Comment: @Lioness100 for my main file this is basically it `const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client()
const ms = require('ms')
const fs = require('fs');
const { execute } = require('./commands/yes');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.events = new Discord.Collection();

['command_handler', 'event_handler'].forEach(handler =>{
    require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client, Discord);
})



client.login(My token);`
oh and stackoverflow said to not extend this and bring to chat or something

Comment: Actually, it works now. I just put `client` before `member`